# Verify that the contravariant powerset functor does indeed satisfy the criteria of a contravariant functor

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification

Could anyone check my working please?

---

$F:\mathscr C \to \mathscr D$ is a contravariant functor (as opposed to a covariant functor) if it assigns to $f:a \to b$ an arrow $F(f): F(b)\to F(a)$, such that

1. $F(1_a)=1_{F(a)}$
2. $F(g\circ f)=F(f)\circ F(g)$

A contravariant powerset functor $ \bar{\mathscr P}:Set \to Set$ takes each set $A$ to its powerset $\mathscr P(A)$, and each $f:A \to B$ to the function $\bar{\mathscr P}(f):\mathscr P(B) \to \mathscr P(A)$ that assigns to $X\subseteq B$ its inverse image $f^{-1}(X)\subseteq A$.

We begin with 1, and assume that $\bar{\mathscr P}(1_A)$. $\bar{\mathscr P}(1_A)=\bar{\mathscr P}(A)=1_{\bar{\mathscr P}(A)}$. The proof for an arbitrary function $f$ is very similar.

For 2, assume $\bar{\mathscr P}(g\circ f)$. Let $f:A \to B$ and $g:B\to C$. Then $g\circ f:A\to C$. By def $\bar{\mathscr P}(g\circ f):\mathscr P(C)\to \mathscr P(A)$ assigns to each $X\subseteq C$ its inverse image $(g\circ f)^{-1}(X)\subseteq A$.

On the other hand, starting with $\bar{\mathscr P}(f)\circ \bar{\mathscr P}(g)$ on the RHS, $\bar{\mathscr P}(g):\mathscr P(C)\to \mathscr P(B)$ assigns to each $X\subseteq C$ its inverse image $g^{-1}(X)\subseteq B$. Likewise, $\bar{\mathscr P}(f):\mathscr P(B)\to \mathscr P(A)$ assigns to each $X\subseteq B$ its inverse image $f^{-1}(X)\subseteq A$.

Beginning with $\bar{\mathscr P}(g)(X)$, we get $g^{-1}(X)\subseteq B$, but by applying $\bar{\mathscr P}(f)$ we get $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}(X)\subseteq A$. But we know the inverse of a composition is the same as the composition of the inverses, ie. $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}=(g\circ f)^{-1}$, thus $\bar{\mathscr P}(f)\circ \bar{\mathscr P}(g)=\bar{\mathscr P}(g\circ f)$.

Comment: "But we know the inverse of a composition is the same as the composition of the inverses" is not equivalent to $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(X)) = (f \circ g)^{-1}(X)$ since $f$ and $g$ might not *have* inverses. Try and prove that the sets $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(X))$ and $(f \circ g)^{-1}(X)$ are equal.

Comment: @NoelLundström I am sorry but did you mean proving $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(X))$ is equal to $(g\circ f)^{-1}(X)$?

Comment: Yes! Silly mistake on my part, that's what I meant!

Comment: @NoelLundström I am sorry but I really don't know to do that; I am suspecting that we can take $\bar{\mathscr P}(f\circ g)$ as the inverse of $g\circ f$, and likewise for $f$ and $g$? Could you give me a hint please?

Comment: If $x \in f^{-1}(g^{-1}(X))$ then $f(x) \in g^{-1}(X)$ which implies $g(f(x)) \in X$ but that also implies that $(g \circ f)(x) \in X$ which shows that $x \in (g \circ f)^{-1}(X)$. This shows that $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(X)) \subset (g \circ f)^{-1}(X)$, you do the other inclusion

Comment: @NoelLundström If we assume $x\in(g\circ f)^{-1}(X)$, then we get $g\circ f(x)\in X$, and we can then start moving the functions back to the other side, ie. $g(x)\in f^{-1}(X) \to x\in g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(X)$

Does this sound right?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: @NoelLundström Thank you so much fellow Gothenburgnian! :)